# Blob Storage Server with REST API

Tags: rest, file-io, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am looking for a solution similar to Amazon S3 or Azure Blob Storage that can be hosted internally instead of remotely. I don't necessarily need to scale out, but I'd like to create a central location where my growing stable of apps can take advantage of file storage. I would also like to formalize file access. Does anybody know of anything like the two services I mentioned above?

I could write this myself, but if something exists then I'd rather now reinvent the wheel, unless that weel has corners :)

Answer (score 1):

The only real alternative to services like S3 and Azure blobs I've seen is Swift, though if you don't plan to scale out this may be overkill for your specific scenario.

> The OpenStack Object Store project, known as Swift, offers cloud storage software so that you can store and retrieve lots of data in virtual containers. It's based on the Cloud Files offering from Rackspace.
>
> The OpenStack Object Storage API is implemented as a set of ReSTful (Representational State Transfer) web services. All authentication and container/object operations can be performed with standard HTTP calls

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/